# RASA - Chat Bot - Specification Details

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I am trying to create a rasa chat bot
i referred the following link to create a chat bot
[Rasa X  installation](https://medium.com/devang-chavda/a-step-by-step-guide-to-install-and-set-up-the-environment-for-rasa-x-in-windows-without-docker-cab263b51342)
i tried in windows system and installation completed and working good
then a tried the same in Linux(ububdu) server. but its not working properly..
first it shows issue with tensor flow an i changed its version and installed
after installation , i tried to execute the command

'rasa init --no-prompt'

and showing the error

'rasa init --no-prompt Illegal instruction (core dumped)'

Here i want some clarification based on this

i am using python 3.6.8

1. What are the Hardware and OS specification for using this in  both Linux(Ubuntu) and windows server
2. after using the command  'rasa run' its running on localhost:5005 , How can i change it to another ip
3. is it possible to get the response from another resource ?

   and how can i implement this ?

   eg : input given as  who is the founder of Infosys Company ? , then i want to  find the
   response from google , from the website of infosys (like the general question like
   who is Indian prime minister , what is current data and time.. etc)
   how can i do this ?
4. Is it possible to use Postgresql for database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What are the Hardware and OS specification for using this in both Linux(Ubuntu) and windows server

You can find [the most recent requirements here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/install/quick-install-script/#quick-install-script-requirements), but currently they are:

- Ubuntu 16.04/18.04  OR Debian 9/10 (although I ran into some wrinkles with Debian 10 today) OR Red Hat 7/8 OR CentOS 7/8
- 2+ vCPUs
- 4 GB + RAM (8 GB recommended)
- 50 GB disk space

2. after using the command 'rasa run' its running on localhost:5005 , How can i change it to another ip

The easiest way to change it to a different IP would be to install it on a server. Local mode will always run on localhost by default. [You can find installation guides here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/installation-guide/).

3. is it possible to get the response from another resource ?

It sounds like you're talking about making an external API call as part of your assistant's functionality. If I'm right, the best way to do that is using an action server. This is a second server running whatever arbitrary code you need that your assistant communicates with using the SDK.[This YouTube video has a nice walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9POI7LiKH_8).

4. Is it possible to use Postgresql for database

If you mean to store the conversations, then use. You can set up a tracker store to store your conversation history and specify that you want to use postgresql. You can [find the docs here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/tracker-stores/).